# Is there an opposite "-ism" word to nepotism?

Tags: meaning, antonyms, productive-affixes

Is there an opposite "-ism" word to nepotism? If *nepotism* refers to the nature of favoring one due to familial or friendly relations, surely there is an antonym to nepotism that conveys the favoring of one due to merit or productivity.

However, "meritism" and "productivism" are not words. Meritorious and   productivity work in a pinch to address one's  point, but the   tense and  usage are less  helpful when a single "-ism" word  could carry the point more concisely.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: 'Meritocracy' fits everything but '-ism'.

Comment: Objective, objectivism, maybe.

Comment: Alas, @LucianSava, that word has already been claimed by Ayn Rand as the name of her dubious philosophical system.

Comment: You can see [Examples of Objectivism in Everyday Life](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-objectivism.html) *Making decisions that are based on reason as opposed to emotions and that which cannot be seen*, @Juhasz.

Comment: I suggest 'equity' in its 'equitable' sense.

Comment: There are a few isms I can think of related to the principle of "To each according to his contribution." Seriously though, "egalitarianism" is quite starkly contrastive with "nepotism".

Comment: It's interesting that you take the opposite of nepotism to be favouring someone due to merit. Why not favouring someone who is not related? Or *disfavouring* someone who *is* related? As far as I can tell, favouring someone due to merit is no more the opposite of favouring someone who is related than is favouring someone who is short . . .

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Jason. You wrote: "It's interesting that you take the opposite of nepotism to be favouring someone due to merit." This could be a cultural reality more than a strictly linguistic truth, as you addressed, but in the USA especially there is a great cry against favoritism toward family and friends. The problem addressed is nepotism motivating hiring decisions rather than meritorious ability. Sometimes the worry is legitimate, and other times the worry is selfishly motivated. This is why I am looking for this specifically (if it exists).

Comment: @Zebrafish what is stopping you from posting an answer. Egalitarianism is best fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are a few isms I can think of related to the principle of "To
>   each according to his contribution." Seriously though,
>   "egalitarianism" is quite starkly contrastive with "nepotism". –
>   Zebrafish Mar 9 at 0:25

Since this format isn't very user friendly, I need to post the answer here. I was hoping there'd be another word to use here, as egalitarianism can sometimes be tied to Christian religious perspectives, but this is currently the best option I have heard as the opposite of "nepotism."

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any opposite word ending with "ism". Many or most words with the *suffix "**-ism**"* have been formed to carry a negative connotation. I suggest using the *negation* *prefix "**anti-**"* to establish a clear opposite of whatever "ism" word is used. In this case it would be "**anti-nepotism**". It would probably work equally well for any of them - the formed *anti-* word now carrying a double negative effect.

Comment: I wasn't able to find one either, which is why I asked, to see if the worldwide collection could locate something I don't. How would "anti-nepotism" be a double negative? I think of a double negative like "I don't not like her."

Comment: Nepotism is considered a "negative" practice. So, anti-nepotism would generally carry a "positive" meaning or connotation. It is "good" to be "against something that is bad".